# Problem with spring RestTemplate POST request

Tags: java, spring, rest

Trying to make a post call on one of our servers, but getting 400 BAD_REQUEST all the time

```
   static void postUserToken()
    {
        final String url = "SERVER ADDRESS";
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        MultiValueMap<String, String> requestBody= new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        requestBody.add("userName", "TESTUSER");
        requestBody.add("password", "TESTPASSWORD");
        requestBody.add("auth", "secEnterprise");

        HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> request = new HttpEntity<>(requestBody, headers);

        ResponseEntity<String> response =  restTemplate.postForEntity(url, request, String.class );

        System.out.println(response);
    }
```

get request to the same address works, post request via Postman works fine with the same body and headers

what am I missing ?

EDIT

calls from postman

```
POST /api/call/ HTTP/1.1
Host: SEREVERADDRESS:6405
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.15.0
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: token1,token2
Host: SEREVERADDRESS:6405
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
content-length: 92
Connection: keep-alive
cache-control: no-cache

{
    "password": "PASSWORD",
    "auth": "secEnterprise",
    "userName": "USER"
}
```

in response I get an object like this {"token":"longtoken"}

Comment: please attach the postman request and response that is successful.

Comment: You can debug restTemplate.postForEntity to see the exact request that's being generated

Comment: When you are passing user name and password auth token, I think user name and password are not required. You have to pass only auth token. You can check the Swagger details if any for this request.

Comment: @dassum it's under the edit

Comment: @Sambit in this case I need to pass login and password for sure

Comment: First time call, you may pass user name and password which may return an auth code which should be passed as header in other susbsequent call. If you provide the REST call details, people will be able to help you.

Comment: @Sambit yes that's exactly what i'm trying to get; passing login and password to get back a token that would be used in headers

Comment: Are you using Http Client for this ?

Comment: In your postman call you are generating proper json by yourself while in the code you send different data. Create an entity and then covert it to the json string with ObjectMapper

Comment: By entity I mean a DTO with all three parameters set (that will be a substitution for MultyValueMap). Then you just feed this object to json converter and get a valid json string which you then attach to the request as a body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a `MultiValueMap` however the json you send from postman looks like a simple `Map`.

This will produce `{"key1":["val1"]}` instead of `{"key1":"val1"}`

Comment: thanks, I got that MultyValueMap from all the samples online; and I was questioning that [] around the values; now when i changed it to me just a map, everything seems working and I get my response from the server

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be in the

```
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
```

Try using `headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);` or convert your data to a proper JSON.

More on this: https://www.baeldung.com/rest-template (4.4. Submit Form Data)

Comment: no this media type returns me 415 -  Unsupported Media Type, already tested

Comment: @VladimirZaguzinThat's because your endpoint on the server expects the proper JSON data while you are sending '&' separated values.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand the problem and since I do not know your rest call details, I provide below the approach you can try.

Remove the following line.

```
requestBody.add("auth", "secEnterprise");
```

Add the line

```
headers.setHeader("auth", "secEnterprise");
```

If you are using other version of Apache Http Client, you can use the following code snippet.

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
httpPost.addHeader("header-name" , "header-value");
```